# What does a browser session mean in the context of chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Please note, this question is not about client-server sessions. It's about Chrome session.

I'm reading [this article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) about `tabId` and it states that:

> Tab IDs are unique within a browser session.

What is browser session here? Does the session begin when I open a browser and ends when I close it? Is there a way to track tab across sessions?

Comment: @Claudius, the question you linked to has nothing to do with `session` in the context of an extension. The `session` explained in the linked answer is related to server side development

Comment: @Claudius, please unmark this question as a duplicate

Comment: In short, a session is user/person-based and lasts while any window belonging to that user/person's profile exists. The implementation has [peculiarities on various platforms](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/sessions/session_service.cc?rcl=1472733616&l=112) and needs investigation. There's also [sessions API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions). That's all I know for now, so I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is browser session here? Does the session begin when I open a browser and ends when I close it?

That's correct. It means a tab will preserve its ID only until you close the browser.

Even if the browser is configured to reopen the previews windows on startup, they will all have a different tab ID and window ID.

> Is there a way to track tab across sessions?

Yes, with the `tabs` permission! Mostly.

The IDs will be different but you can query *all* the open tabs and windows and you will receive the position of a tab in a window (e.g. first tab in window 2) together with its URL. You'd have to regularly query and save this data via `chrome.storage.local.set()`

You can then compare this piece of information to the data you stored before closing the browser and match them to each other. For example you receive `tab on position 1, with URL xyz, in a window with 3 other tabs`, you can find a tab with the same details in your storage.

The *"mostly"* part: If the user has 2 windows with 1 tab, both pointing to the same page, you won't be able to tell which is which.