# Does a chrome session persist when the computer sleeps?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, session-storage

I'm building a chrome extension, and I'm trying to understand exactly what constitutes a browser "session" (as given by [the chrome storage API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/).

I need to run a query periodically to ensure that the user has up-to-date information in the extension, so I'm thinking of running the query when a new session starts. However, I'm wondering exactly what a "session" means. If I close my laptop and it sleeps, do I trigger a new Chrome session, even if the tabs stayed open on my computer? I ask because I personally leave tabs open on my computer, sometimes for days or weeks at a time --- if a user does this, their information is much more likely to become stale, and I'll need to work out a new approach. However if a new session is created upon a sleep-wakeup, then I think I can stick with my current implementation.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279086/what-does-a-browser-session-mean-in-the-context-of-chrome-extension) relating to this question, but no clear answer (other than one answer which suggests that a new session is created if the browser is configured to reopen the previous windows on startup. However it's unclear to me whether a computer sleeping and waking up constitutes reopening previous windows on startup, or simply persisting the existing windows).

Does anybody have any experience with this who can give me some guidance?

Comment: Its the same session. Sleeping (as well as hybernating) is designed to preserve the state of running programs without closing/stopping/reopening.